# Specify SSH Key to use by server IP

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

How can I specify which key to use when connecting to a server by ipaddress?

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
Host 1.2.3.4
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_other_key
```

Answer (score 0):

either use `-i` option as in

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_other_key 1.2.3.4
```

or use IdentityFile in config, correct syntax is

```
Host 1.2.3.4
    IdentityFile=~/.ssh/my_other_key
```

note the indentation in lines after Host keyword.

Comment: the second one is close to what im doing.  so maybe the lack of identation is the problem.